# Sequence $(a_n)_n$ and series $\sum_n \frac{a_n}{n}$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Given a sequence $(a_n)_n$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$, does the series of general term $\frac{a_n}{n}$ have to be convergent? divergent? If it is one of them, prove it. If it is either, give an example.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: Also, to get you started: consider "simple", well-known sequences. For instance, $a_n = \frac{1}{n^p}$ for $p>0$ (the simplest being $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$), $a_n = r^n$ with $r\in(-1,1)$ (geometric, the simplest being $a_n= 1/2^n$), $a_n = \frac{1}{\ln n}$... and see if that tells you anything.

Answer (score 2):

For example:

$$a_n=\frac1{\log n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\;,\;\;\text{but the series}\;\;\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(\frac{a_n}n=\frac1{n\log n}\right)\;\;\text{diverges}$$

say by Cauchy's Condensation Test. Now try with $\;a_n=\frac1n\;$ and you'll get a convergent series, so in general you can't say.

Comment: What a weird place to put an equal sign :-).

Comment: That just avoids writing $\sum$ twice. I sort of like it.